# Create an array of 20 random numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to create an array of 20 random numbers in the range from -10 to 10 inclusive and Check whether all numbers match the parameters (from -10 to 10).
here is my code:

```
let array = [];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

array.push(Math.round((Math.random() * 21) - 10));

}
console.log(array);
```

Comment: This array is only one length long so the for loop won’t run.

Comment: if you change `let array = [20];` to `let array = new Array(20);` your code works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be more like this

```
let array = [];

for(let i=0; i<20; i++){
    array.push(Math.round((Math.random() * 21) - 10));
}
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick,

```js
var array = Array(20).fill().map(() => Math.round(Math.random() * 20) - 10);
    
console.log(array)
```